# More formal definitions for "equation", "expression", "term"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, education

For words like *equation*, *expression*, and *term*, do we have more formal definitions at

- any level (perhaps from set theory, logic, or algebra); or
- at a level suitable for secondary/high-school students?

Or are these simply words that are used loosely and informally?

At the secondary/high-school level, we might usually simply say something like

> an equation has an equals sign, an expression doesn't.

Or we might give an example like the picture below. But I was wondering if we could do a little better.

[image]

Comment: There are formal definitions but each depends on the particular operators and predicates in the particular system. Do you have a particular set of such in mind?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: No I do not and would appreciate if you could point me to any references. I am particularly interested in material that might be suitable for secondary/high-school students.

Comment: The references I have with formal definitions are for the college level.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: That would be fine too. I would like to see if I can "translate" these to something suitable for lower-level students.

Answer (score 3):

A term is generally compromised of a coefficient,a variable and an exponent.

For example, $-4x^3$ is a term with coefficient $-4$, variable $x$ and exponent $3$

An expression is generally compromised of more than one term.

For example $$3x^2-4y+2$$ is an expression  consisting of three terms.

An equation is the statement of equality between two expressions.

The statement may be true for some values of variables called the solutions to equation.

For example $$ x^2-3x+2=0 $$ is an equation which is true if $x=2$ or $x=1$

An identity is the statement of equality  between two expressions whose values are the same for all values of the variables.

For example $(x+y)^2= x^2+2xy+y^2.$

Comment: I'm not so happy with an expression consisting of more than one term. Surely, a polynomial with degree 0 consists of an expression made up of a single term?